# separate appended data from the file android

Tags: android, file, file-io, buffer, fileoutputstream

I am writing data in file continuously in append mode using FileOutputStream. Everything is working fine but I want to separate each appended stream from file while reading it.

Here is how I created file and writing it in Android

```
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = service.openFileOutput("text.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
                        outputStream.write(measurement.toString().getBytes());
                        outputStream.close();
```

It is appending data successfully but when I am reading it I do not know how to find end point between appended strings.

Here is my code to read the string from file

```
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            FileInputStream inputStream = service.openFileInput("text.txt");
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            r.close();
            inputStream.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "File Size: "+total.length());
```

Comment: You are reading lines but you are not writing lines. Start with writing lines. You could separate your appends by an empty line or whatever you want.

Comment: I am writing line here outputStream.write(measurement.toString().getBytes());

Comment: Yes. I've seen that of course. But why would that be a line?

Comment: sorry, but I dont understand what do you mean, I have content in measurement variable and writing it into text.txt

Comment: That i see to. But i cannot see the content. And i think it is not a line. You have to tell why a line is written. You could give an example of the content so we could see if it is a line.

Comment: actually this measurement is an JSON Object that I am converting to String and writing it ...and writing works fine, can you explain what do you mean by "line" while writing data

Comment: A line is string content that ends on a newline character. "\n". If you use readLine() then all text until the first \n is read. So is the last character you append a \n?

Comment: so it means it adds new line character everytime new measurement data comes and gets written in file...am I understood right ..?

Comment: No you should add every time a \n if you want to write lines and if there isn't already a \n. But stop....  your json string will contain a lot of newlines already. Is that true? If so then add after everey append some empty lines.

Comment: yes true, but that was my question, how to add that new empty line...as i could not find any append method for fileoutputstream class in android

Comment: You could add newlines to measurement.toString() first. Or just call write() again. Try write("\n".getBytes());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references, it is silly that I have not tried but thanks to @greenapps

I just had to add another write statement to append

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = service.openFileOutput("text.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
                        outputStream.write(measurement.toString().getBytes());
                        outputStream.write("\n".getBytes());
                        outputStream.close();
```

for reading saparated string I simply used split for java

```
   String[] parts = total.toString().split("\n");
                    for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                      Log.d(TAG, parts[i]);
                    }
                   deleteFile("text.txt");
```